# UI Layout Rows and Columns

Tags: python, interface, add-on

Hello I was wondering how i can make the Value slider expand and take up the unused area (become wider)

The label "slider" should be on the left as it is but the slider somehow will not use the empty space.

picture attached:

[image]

I have tried a few combinations in draw:

[image]

Comment: provide the entire `draw` function

Comment: i added picture of the draw section related to the row

Answer (score 2):

```py
import bpy


class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Demo"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene
        
        split = layout.split(factor=0.2)
        
        col = split.column()
        col.label(text='Slider')
        
        col = split.column()
        col.prop(scene, "frame_start", text='')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```